# Read the cat output with specific range of the letters

Tags: linux, bash, unix, stdout

I digged the stackoverlow and Superuse but I couldn't find answer for my need.

I need to read the output  with range of line.

```
cat try.txt

00aa00nnn0123 Just trying to know
```

I just want to read the line of range 1 to 13 f.e just this line

> 00aa00nnn0123

The file just has one line.

Maybe answer will be so simple but I really struggle with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Bash (substring) parameter expansion syntax ${str:position:length}

Read contents of `try.txt` into variable

```
var=$(<try.txt)
```

Now extract first 13 characters from variable

```
echo "${var:0:13}"
00aa00nnn0123
```

Comment: That is intersting knowladge about the echo thanks for the information

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to read the line of range 1 to 13

Josué Carvajal's answer will read the first word for the file. If you really want to extract the text by the character offset 1 to 13, you can use the `cut` command:

```bash
$ cut -c 1-13 try.txt 
00aa00nnn0123
```

The `cut` command can also extract based on a delimiter, for example:

```bash
cut -d' ' -f 1 try.txt
```

Comment: This is the command that I exact need. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If your file follows that pattern for example:

```
00aa00nnn0123 Just trying to know0
00aa00nnn0124 Just trying to know1
00aa00nnn0125 Just trying to know2
```

You can use `awk` to achieve this, for example

```
❯ cat try.txt| awk '{print $1}'                                                                                                
00aa00nnn0123
00aa00nnn0124
00aa00nnn0125
```

Where the $1 is the column you want to retrieve, in this case, the first one.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This would usually be written as `awk '{print $1}' try.txt`, to avoid the extra subshell and process creation that is caused by the pipe.

Comment: It does not have a pattern just one line. Thanks for answer !

Comment: @user000001 : make that `awk NF=1`